# Split PySpark Dataframe column into multiple

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe column which has data as below.

```
Column 1
A1,A2
B1
C1,C2
D2
```

I have to split the column into 2 columns based on comma. Output Should be as below.

```
Column 1    Column 2
A1          A2
            B1
C1          C2
            D2
```

I tried using the split() function but my B1 and D2 are getting populated in column 1 instead of column 2. Is there a way to achieve the above output?

Comment: you have fixed 2 columns or it could be N items?

Comment: fixed 2 columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) and [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#size):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, size, col, when

df.withColumn("ar", split(df["Column 1"], ",")) \
  .withColumn("Column 2", when(
                             size(col("ar")) == 1, col("ar")[0])
                             .otherwise(col("ar")[1])) \
  .withColumn("Column 1", when(size(col("ar")) == 2, col("ar")[0])) \
  .drop("ar") \
  .show()

# +--------+--------+
# |Column 1|Column 2|
# +--------+--------+
# |      A1|      A2|
# |    null|      B1|
# |      C1|      C2|
# |    null|      D2|
# +--------+--------+
```

First we split `Column 1` by comma then we access the items of the array conditionally.

Comment: Thank you.. will try this out

Comment: I just changed the `df['ar']` to `col('ar')` since that would probably cause an issue accessing the column value

Comment: Getting an error that "otherwise() can only be applied to a column previously generated by when()"

Comment: Its on the line where we create the Column2

Comment: please copy/paste the exact above code, there might be some parenthesis missing. I just tested it and it works.

Comment: Worked perfectly.. my mistake.. i left a paranthesis